# Optimised update ListView in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Till now, I have coded apps which load listviews completely from web(parsing,etc) or completely from local database. What I intend to develop is a listview which will load from existing local database, and check the web database and fetch only those entries which do not exist in the local cache, and then update the local cache with those new entries.

I had a naive idea of implementing it. There would be a single value in local data about the number of entries in local database. Similarly, there would be a value of number of entries on the web database. Then we can exactly fetch the required number of entries from the web, instead of fetching the entire list again.

Is there some better/easier way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide the best answer. However, couldn't only comparing the amount of items lead to issues? For example, what if the web database had the same amount of items, but some had been deleted and some new ones added? Then, the application would "think" it was in sync, but it could be showing outdated data from the cache, when the web database has something completely different. Just something to think about.

Comment: yes. deletions will cause problems. the idea that I had in mind was that of a app for updating commentary. Such apps would not require deletions as such. Even in case of deletions, maybe we can keep a separate counter and a separate database to track how many entries and which entries are getting deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. The better thing to do would be to do this checking on a middle layer server. It would be like a 3 layer application. There would be a middle layer which would store all the posts seen by the current user. So next time user wants to update himself, the middle layer can check what results were posted back to him last time